# A class with an array member of generic rank

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generic-programming

Consider the following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, std::size_t Rank, std::size_t... In>
struct help;

template<typename T, std::size_t... In>
struct help<T, 1, In...> 
{
    static constexpr auto a = std::make_tuple(In...);
    T data[std::get<0>(a)];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... In>
struct help<T, 2, In...>
{
    static constexpr auto a = std::make_tuple(In...);
    T data[std::get<0>(a)][std::get<1>(a)];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... In>
class foo : public help<T, sizeof...(In), In...>
{
private:
    using base = help<T, sizeof...(In), In...>;

public:
    template<typename... Tn>
    constexpr foo(Tn&&... args)
        : base{ { args... } } // constructor would only work if rank == 1
    {}
              T operator[](std::size_t i)       noexcept { return base::data[i]; }
    constexpr T operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept { return base::data[i]; }
};

int main() 
{   
    foo<int, 6> a = {  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  };

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

This is as far as I got.

I'm trying to make a class, objects of which shall be constructed as `foo<int, 2>; foo<int, 3, 4>; foo<int, 1, 2, 3, 4>;` These objects will hold an array member respectively of type `int[2]; int[3][4]; int[1][2][3][4]`.

My initial thinking was to make a helper template class which would specialize quite a lot (at least until an array of rank 20). That is obviously verbose, and after I get to an array of rank 2, I have no idea what the constructor for `foo` should be.

The constructor problem can be solved by making the class a POD (no access specifiers, etc) and construct via aggregate initialization (much like `std::array` does), but that goes against my work so far with the "proper inherited specialization".

I would appreciate some ideas. How would you go about doing something like this?

Comment: Why do you need the array member? Can you have something which emulates the same behavior via multiple `operator[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. Just make a type trait that gives you the correct `std::array` type:

```
template <class T, size_t... Is>
struct multi_array;

template <class T, size_t... Is>
using multi_array_t = typename multi_array<T, Is...>::type;
```

With zero dimensions, you just get the type:

```
template <class T>
struct multi_array<T> {
    using type = T;
};
```

and with at least one dimension, you just wrap it in `std::array` and recurse:

```
template <class T, size_t I, size_t... Is>
struct multi_array<T, I, Is...> {
    using type = std::array<multi_array_t<T, Is...>, I>;
};
```

So you get something like:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<multi_array_t<int, 2>, std::array<int, 2>>::value, "!");
static_assert(std::is_same<multi_array_t<int, 3, 4>, std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3> >::value, "!");
```

Comment: I was definitely overcomplicating. Probably because I wasn't thinking in terms of `std::array` but of C arrays instead. Really elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DeiDei You could do the same with raw arrays too, just change the recursive step.